# how to get next month's date and it's not related to current month date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three columns in my table, future 3 months like fistdate(next month), secondate(+2 next month) and thirdate(+3 next month) which are DATE types. I want to save my dates as follows 09/09/2017, 09/10/2017 and 09/11/2017 and current month is 07/08/2017 and above 3 dates are not related to current month date like 07/08/2017

I have tried following code but it is related to current month

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 month'));
    $date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 month'));

     $install = array(
        "invoiceid"              =>$this->input->post('salesInvoiceno', TRUE),
        "fistdate"               =>$date1,
        "secondate"              =>$date2,
        "thirdate"               =>$date3
    );
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. While its nice that you tell us what yo want to do, you haven't really asked a question. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. Also, be sure that you know that stackoverflow is here to HELP you, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried, share your thoughts with us. Nobody is going to write code for you.

Comment: You do NOT want to store your dates in any format other than that expected by the RDBMS. You are confusing data storage with data display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$time = strtotime("2010-08-06");$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month',$time));$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 month',$time));$date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 month',$time));echo $date1.'    '.$date2.'    '.$date3;

Comment: Thanks@user3564960

Comment: Bro I have changed a little bit and it is working as I aspected as follows: $time = strtotime(date('Y-m-09',time())); //strtotime("2010-08-06");
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month',$time));
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 month',$time));
$date3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 month',$time));
echo $date1.' '.$date2.' '.$date3;